# Selenium with VPN Is MUST

Tags: python, selenium

So I made a program that start  browser[ Edge] with Selenium in Python3.9. I VPN IS MUST.

When I try to start my script with the VPN active, Selenium  does not open edge  . Otherwise, it works when I start the script with inactive VPN .I don't understart what can be the problem.
i use this Code:

```
import sys
import urllib.parse
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
def main(args):
def quote(arg):
if ' ' in arg:
arg = '"%s"' % arg
return urllib.parse.quote_plus(arg)

qstring = '+'.join(quote(arg) for arg in args)
url = urllib.parse.urljoin('https:// ........', '?q=' + qstring)
webbrowser.open(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Error:
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='msedgedriver.azureedge.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_86 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000251D139FFA0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

Comment: the webdriver's communications via the wire protocol will be using localhost methinks... these may be going through the VPN.  So the localhost is no longer you.  You'll want to ensure that the webdriver can communicate to the browser without going through the VPN.  (A clue that this is the issue is that the browser will launch, but then just sit there and do nothing...)

Comment: on 2nd thought, what might be happening here could have to do with your use of the webdrivermanager.  Try taking that out.  (download and initialize the edgedriver manually.)  I say that because of this part of the error: "url: /LATEST_RELEASE_86"  that sounds like a call to the manager's repo or something...

Comment: I should use webDrivermanager ,Itry to test it without VPN ,it's RUN .But I should use selenium to Automate this web App .....